# No grub on dual boot linux mint 20.1 and window 10 install - Lenovo T440s

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, linux-mint

I am getting no grub/boot menu on my dual boot installation of Linux Mint, it just loads Windows 10 straight away (machine is Lenovo T440s Thinkpad)

Formatted drive, fresh windows 10 install, followed by installation of Linux Mint using the default installation process.

From reading online I suspected a BIOS issue. Have attempted multiple changes within the BIOS and reinstalls and no luck. Also thought there was a conflict between Mint as UEFI and Windows Legacy bios setup - so created a new USB from a legacy boot, still no change.

```
Current BIOS settings: 
Legacy Only 
CSM - Yes 

Security Chip Disabled 
Secure Boot Disabled
```

Have also switched off fast boot within windows.

Comment: Are you getting an error installing grub, or does the install appear to complete and you are just not seeing it on boot? Have you tried holding RIGHT-SHIFT on boot or anything else?

Comment: the install of linux mint completes and it just boots into windows 10 

If I go into the boot menu in the BIOS, it only lists HDD's - and the main HDD with both Win10 and Mint on as a single drive. There is no options in the boot menu to select or prioritise a specific boot manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Linux Mint expert, but you can follow this guide here(just replace every instance of `pacman -S` with `apt install`):
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I can't actually boot into Mint at all!

Comment: Do you still have your installation medium? You can still access your system from there.

Comment: I tried something similar as described here: https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiboot.html 

/// and got this error: 
mint@mint:~$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda5
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: Do you have an external drive? You should probably back up all of your data on that drive onto an external one, and then re-install mint, but this time make sure when you get to the part where you are creating system partitions, make sure that your partition is formatted as ext4, instead of ext2.

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way is to Install Hasleo EasyUEFI.
Open it and choose Manage EFI Boot Option
Select Windows Boot Manager
Then disable it (There is an enable disable button)
That is it. Restart and check for yourself.